# Pending Intent triggered by Alarm Manager seems to fire right away

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have set up an Alarm Manager that is supposed to trigger a Pending Intent at a certain time of day.

I placed the code in the onCreate() method of my Main Activity, as I believed this was the best place to put it?

Below is the code:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4); // trigger at 4am in the morning
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    final Intent updateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    updateIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
            "com.example.myotherapp",
            "com.example.myotherapp.MainActivity");
    updateIntent.setComponent(cn);
    updateIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, updateIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent); // launch at 4am, then every day (24 hours)
```

The Alarm Manager works, I can see it fire at the specified time, but it also seems that the Pending Intent is fired as soon as this base app starts.

What is causing the Intent to fire right away? And how can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: First of all check if your `Alarm` you set was added as you expected  
In 'Command Line' paste this `adb shell dumpsys alarm > alarms.txt`. And search in alarms.txt with your package name. You shold find something like `RTC_WAKEUP #13: Alarm{41e7daf8 type 0 your.package.name}

    type=0 when=+8h42m36s649ms repeatInterval=10800000 count=1

    operation=PendingIntent{41c6e8b8: PendingIntentRecord{41e7e768 your.package.name broadcastIntent}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4); // trigger at 4am in the morning
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

calendar.getTimeInMillis() will return the timestamp that BEFORE current timestamp (System.currentTimeMillis()) so that is why Alarm fire right away.

To fix your problem:

```
long triggerTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
if (triggerTime  <= System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000) 
{
    // 3 Second distance

   calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // Add 1 day --> Trigger 1 day later from now
}
```

IF you always want to start your alarm at 4am 1 day later. You can remove condition and doing like this:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // Add 1 day --> Calendar time will be tomorrow 4am
```

AND

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

Comment: What is the 3 second delay for?

Comment: It is only for the case calendar.getTimeInMillis() is very close to System.currentTimeMillis() SO you don't want to start Alarm right away. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You set the alarm to trigger at 4 am today, not tomorrow. Because that time has already passed, the alarm triggers immediatelly.

Comment: The calendar is simply set to 4:00, no day is specified. If you set your phones alarm for 8am in the morning, just before you go to bed, does it go off right away because 8am has already passed? No it doesn't.

Comment: `calendar.getInstance()` returns current date and time. When you change the time to 4 am, you change time but not date. The system alarm application changes the date as well (it automatically sets tomorrow if the time has already passed).

Comment: @StenSoft was right, so I'm upvoting to counterbalance the unjustified downvote.